# xcrysden 1.5.53: unable to resolve host address `prdownloads.sourceforge.net'

Tags: tar

I'm Mayuri.
When I tried to install `xcrysden 1.5.53` in Ubuntu, I ran into the difficulty below:

After running the commands:

```
tar xvf xcrysden-1.5.53.tar.gz && cd xcrysden-1.5.53/
cp system/Make.sys-shared Make.sys
make all
```

I get:

```
#------------------------------------#
#                                    #
#   Downloading external Tcl-library #
#                                    #
#------------------------------------#

--2015-06-11 12:49:07--  http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/tcl/tcl8.5.11-src.tar.gz
Resolving prdownloads.sourceforge.net (prdownloads.sourceforge.net)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `prdownloads.sourceforge.net'
make[1]: *** [tcl] Error 4
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/physics2/Desktop/xcrysden-1.5.53/external/src'
make: *** [tcl] Error 2
physics2@CP2:~/Desktop/xcrysden-1.5.53$
```

Comment: Mayuri, I rewrote your post a bit, let me know if I made a mistake somewhere :)

Comment: Can you ping the host?

Answer (score 1):

Your probably took the least easiest to install download (the bare source code version).

It is always best to use the debian installer file if it is available since that installer is created for Debian and Ubuntu and will pick up dependencies itself from the software center.

- [1.5.53-1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/uk/trusty/all/xcrysden-data/download) (=14.04; Trusty and the same for 14.10; Utopic) can be downloaded from the packages page. That should be the same version as you want to install.
- There is a newer version too [1.5.60](http://packages.ubuntu.com/uk/vivid/xcrysden-data) (=15.04; Vivid).

You can use Ubuntu Software Center to install this.

---

They also have [pre-compiled version](http://www.xcrysden.org/download/xcrysden-1.5.53-linux_x86_64-semishared.tar.gz). That one is easier to install:

> 1. unpack the xc-VERSION.tar.gz package file
>           e.g., as: tar zxvf xc-VERSION.tar.gz
>                 or: gunzip -c xc-VERSION.tar.gz | tar xvf -
> 2. cd into the so-created directory (i.e., cd xcrysden-VERSION/)
> 3. launch the program as "./xcrysden"

---

All the other ones need compiling. If there is no need for you to use a compiled version the 2 methods above should suffice to get this installed.

Next to that they also provide a [version](http://Source%20package:%20standalone:%20xc-1.5.24-src.tar.gz%20with%20Tcl/Tk/Mesa%20libraries%20included:%20xc-1.5.24-src-all.tar.gz) with TCL/TK/MESA included and one [standalone](http://www.xcrysden.org/download/xc-1.5.24-src.tar.gz) source code versions. These error out on me when installing with the same message as yours so the installation script seems faulty. Drop a comment on their [mailinglist](http://www.xcrysden.org/XCrySDen.html#mailing-list) if you want to get this fixed.